# How to read a txt file in MPI by a single process? Why my approach does not work?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I new to MPI.
I am trying to read a text file by using standard c++ code as follows.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[] ){

int np, pid, ierr;
ierr = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
ierr = MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &np);
ierr = MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &pid);


const int imgWidth = 1000; // the width of the image (count in pixel)
const int imgHeight = 1000; // the height of the image

double* Y;
Y = (double *)malloc(imgHeight*imgWidth*sizeof(double));

if(pid == 0)
{
    string input = "Im.txt";
    readData(input.c_str(), Y);
}
MPI_Bcast(Y, imgHeight*imgWidth, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


free(Y);

MPI_Finalize();

return 1;
```

}

The readData function is defined as:

```
bool readData(const char *fileName, double* Y){

printf("Reading the data file!\n");

ifstream fin(fileName);

int i = 0;
while(fin>>Y[i])
{   
    i++;
};
cout<<"In total, "<<i<<" data are imported."<<endl;
//close the file
fin.close();

return 1;
```

}

The file "Im.txt" includes a bunch of numbers. However, when I run the program, there is no data imported. Can anyone give me a hint? I do not need to use multiply processes to read this file in parallel.

Comment: have you tried printing out the data as the cursor reads it? this can help you isolate where the bug is coming from. does readData return anything? can you open the file to begin with? any exceptions being raised?

Comment: I add a breakpoint in the line "if(pid ==0)" and then execute the program step by step. When the program goes to the line "readData(input.c_str());", the program opens a file named "xstring" automatically and will not actually go to the readData function. I just do not understand why.

Comment: It seems fin can not open the file. I tried to use C style function fopen and fscanf, they still can not open the file. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Finally, I find the problem. I am working under win7 with visual studio. Seems I have to indicate explicitly the path of my file. Even I put "Im.txt" to the same folder with the source code file, it does not work.

Comment: @mining, if you've answered your own question, go ahead and post it as an answer and mark it as correct so this question is closed.

Comment: @WesleyBland, thanks for your reminder and it's done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find the problem. I am working under win7 with visual studio. Seems I have to indicate explicitly the path of my file. Even I put "Im.txt" to the same folder with the source code file, it does not work.